# Conda does not look for libpthread and libpthread_nonshared at the right place when compiling inside an env

Tags: python, gcc, conda, setuptools

I have a python package with a Cython extension that I'm trying to compile.

I get the following error as the output of `pip install`:

```
 /home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -pthread -shared 
     -B /home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/compiler_compat -L/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/lib -Wl,
     -rpath=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ 
     -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined 
     -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/lib 
     -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/lib -L/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/lib -march=nocona 
     -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe 
     -isystem /home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/include -DNDEBUG 
     -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/celer/lasso_fast.o 
     -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/celer/lasso_fast.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib64/libpthread.so.0

/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These libs are not in /usr/lib64, they are in `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib64/`

Why is conda's compiler not finding them ? I'm suspecting the option `-sysroot=/`, whereas the default value points to the correct location

```
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ --print-sysroot
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/benchopt_lasso/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot
```

Steps to reproduce (with another package), in a fresh terminal, with the following `env.yml` file:

```
name: reprod 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
  - cython
  - compilers
  - pip
```

```
conda env create -n reprod -f env.yml
conda activate reprod 
pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/mathurinm/cd_solver.git@module_structure -v
```

Changing to python=3.9 in the env requirement solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - when building a project with `pyproject.toml`, the default is to use [build-isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation). This install `setuptools` from `pypi`, which is not configured to work with conda compilers. If you use the option `--no-build-isolation`, the package builds.

---

The issue here is that `pyproject.toml` build isolation process is not compatible with `conda` env that have its own compilers. There has been several report of this incompatibility, for instance this is mentionned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6144#issuecomment-459433190).

The core issue here is that `setuptools` relies on a package called `sysconfigdata_xxx` to get info on how to build packages (see [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/46591cfae8bd2d9fd7164a66b670d58578e8ff6c/setuptools/_distutils/sysconfig.py#L455)) and in particular fetch the linker flags. By default, it fetches the package `'_sysconfigdata_{abi}_{platform}_{multiarch}'`. When `setuptools` is installed with conda, it is [patched](https://github.com/conda-forge/setuptools-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/patches/0010-Add-support-for-_CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME-if-.patch) to fetch a different sysconfig defined in the env variable `_CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME`, set in the conda env. The `_sysconfig_*` module then uses the correct compilation flags.

With the build isolation, a new env is create (on linux in `/tmp/pip-build-env-XXX/`) and a new version of `setuptools`, different from the one in `conda` is installed.  This reverts setuptools to the orignal behavior, *i.e.* fetching the orignal `_sysconfig_*` file. In python3.8, this package set the flag `--sysroot=/` for the linker flags. Thus, the shared library for `pthread` are search not in `conda` libraries but in system `/lib64` where it seems the right version are not present, which explains why this breaks for this config. This `_sysconfig_*` module has been changed in `python3.9`, and the `--sysroot=/` flag is not set anymore. This is why it work on `python3.9`.

To solve this without breaking the build isolation, I think the best way would be to manage to automatically set `_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME` (which is the primary source to find the module name) to point on `_CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME` (which point to the right config) in the build env when it is called. This requires patching `pip` with the following patch (this works locally when patching pip in the reproducer env):

```
index daeb7fb..a1c92b4 100644
--- a/pip/_internal/build_env.py
+++ b/pip/_internal/build_env_modified.py
@@ -128,7 +128,8 @@ class BuildEnvironment:
     def __enter__(self) -> None:
         self._save_env = {
             name: os.environ.get(name, None)
-            for name in ("PATH", "PYTHONNOUSERSITE", "PYTHONPATH")
+            for name in ("PATH", "PYTHONNOUSERSITE", "PYTHONPATH",
+                         "_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME")
         }
 
         path = self._bin_dirs[:]
@@ -145,6 +146,8 @@ class BuildEnvironment:
                 "PYTHONPATH": os.pathsep.join(pythonpath),
             }
         )
+        if '_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME' not in os.environ:
+            os.environ['_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME'] = os.environ['_CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME']
 
     def __exit__(
         self,
```

Maybe this could be propagated on `conda-forge/pip-feedstock` but this seems unpractical. I did not see any way to change env variable in the pip build system just with config files or `setup.py`.